# Found an `unsalvageable` question but 0 flags remaining

Tags: discussion, feature-request

At present, I can flag 12 times per day. After 12 flags, if I find an unsalvageable question, how should I flag it?
My request is that SO should consider **refilling flag for each accepted flag.**
E.g.: if a user raises 5 flags (remaining 7 flags), among the 5, if 3 are accepted, then the 3 should be refilled (remaining 10 flags) for that day to make a good improvement in quality.

Comment: It's not too bad as you start to gain flags. What I would do is make a comment on the question itself for future readers who may consider flagging the question themselves. I usually just post the description of the flag. As an example for too broad: _There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs._

Comment: @Bugs Good point! I took the liberty of adding that into my answer. (With attribution, of course).

Answer (score 6):

We already have a system for this. For every 10 flags deemed helpful, you will be given an extra flag. You also get more flags per day when your reputation increases - 1 extra flag for every 2000 points. There is a maximum of 100 flags per day.

If you are out of flags, and see something that needs flagging, you can go to a chatroom and raise the issue there.
The [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) will usually be happy to help. You post a "close request" with the following format:

```
[tag:cv-pls] Reason why this question should be closed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linktothepost
```

Just to be on the safe side, you should probably read their [rules and explanation](http://socvr.org/) before posting in the SOCVR; that website is also linked from the room.
After you've posted a CV request, the other users there will see if it does indeed need closing. And then act accordingly.

As user @Bugs points out in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344682/found-an-unsalvageable-question-but-0-flags-remaining#comment452268_344682), you can also just comment on the question. This also points out the issue to other visitors, and gives the OP an opportunity to improve their post before it gets closed.

Comment: is flags transferrable?

Comment: @SagarV No. They cannot give you flags. They can use their own flags or close votes to deal with the question.

Comment: You also get another flag per 2000 rep up to a maximum of 100 per day in total.

Comment: What you do is to post a close-vote request in that chat, so that other users can review it and act on it. Syntax `[tag:cv-pls] Reason why this question should be closed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linktothepost`. See this: http://socvr.org/tour

Comment: @Lundin Thanks! Edited that into the answer.